# Entity Framework- Make Font bold with checking conditions for the null data

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am trying to fetch the whole list for Menu. i want to make Parent Menu to be bold using Entity framework code with checking conditions for the null data.

If Data is null then -> to make text will be bold else data will remain basic text.

Entities are :

```
public class MenuItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int MenuItemID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string MenuItemParent { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Product { get; set; }


        //public  List<SelectListItem> MenuItemParents { get; set; }
    }
```

I am adding data with MenuItemparent will be null if it is parent data, if adding child then MenuItemParent data will be based on parent data value.

I want to display the list with Parement Menu bold and child Menu with basic text

Controller's Action :

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {

                return View(db.MenuItems.ToList());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }
```

View :

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MenuItemParent)
                    </th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MenuItemParent.)
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.MenuItemID }) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Detail", new { id = item.MenuItemID }) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.MenuItemID })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

If possible i do not want to check the conditions in it in view. i want only from Ef -viewmodel

Comment: Why is MenuItemParent a string?  It should be an int.  Formatting isn't something for the data layer.  It's a presentation thing and belongs in the View.

Comment: Also, I see no sorting order.  That seems like an oversight.

Comment: Simply use a view model that tells whether something should be displayed in boldface.